What are the most common methods for handling non-stationary environments in reinforcement learning?
What are the most common algorithms, methods for handling non-stationary environments in reinforcement learning?

There're many methods could be exploited for handling non-stationary environments in RL such as ensemble methods (averaging, voting, dynamic), online learning, forgetting old experiences from the replay buffer and episodic control, genetic algorithm, domain generalization, meta-learning, Bayesian learning, contextual bandits and Thompson sampling, etc.
For example model-agnostic meta-learning (MAML) has been applied to nonstationary RL to find an initial policy parameters that can be quickly fine-tuned to new conditions in the environment as required by the few shot learning nature to quickly adapt to any new environment. Based on hierarchical Bayesian model MAML is well suited for few shot meta-learning by learning from the distribution of conditions which correspond to different time periods or different configurations of the nonstationary environment.

Model-Agnostic Meta-Learning (MAML) was introduced in 2017 by Chelsea Finn et al. Given a sequence of tasks, the parameters of a given model are trained such that few iterations of gradient descent with few training data from a new task will lead to good generalization performance on that task... MAML was successfully applied to few-shot image classification benchmarks and to policy-gradient-based reinforcement learning.


Can you explain how genetic algorithms could be used to handle non-stationary environments in reinforcement learning? Also, can you provide a reference that supports your claims (for each of the cases)?
